# Merge indexes in union

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
Table A:
a_id, a_href, a_name,......

Table B:
b_id, b_href, b_name......
```

Both tables have indexes on their href column. I intend to union these tables and join them on another, something like

```
Select c_id, u.name FROM TableC
Left join (Select a_href AS href, a_name AS name FROM TableA
           UNION
           SELECT b_href AS href, b_name AS name FROM TableB) AS u ON u.href = c_href
```

I want to preserve the index on href columns in the union, so my join is fast. Do I have to dynamically create an index for that union, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you *want* `UNION [DISTINCT]` or `UNION ALL`. That is to say, is there a chance that `tablea(a_href,a_name)`, is duplicated as `tableb(b_href,b_name)`

Comment: They *should* not have duplicates in the first place, but if they do, then I would say `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 1):

A `UNION` will not have an index.  A "derived table", which is what you have inside the parens, *may* be given an index -- it depends first on which version of MySQL you are running.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Get rid of `LEFT` so that the Optimizer can start with the `UNION`.  And add `INDEX(href)` in `C` so that the `JOIN` can work the other direction.

If you really need `NULL` for `u.name`, then you need the `LEFT`, and there is no hope for optimizing.

(The default for `UNION` is `UNION DISTINCT`, which is slower than `UNION ALL`.)